# What is this space homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I am given an action of $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$ on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ by $x+iy\mapsto -x+iy$ and $\text{id}:\Bbb{C}^{*}\to\Bbb{C}^{*}$ .

Then what is the orbit space homeomorphic to?.

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289505/orbit-space-of-an-action-of-z2) seems to be the same as my action when defined on cartesian coordinates, i.e. $(x+iy)\sim (-x+iy)$ and it says that the space is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}P^{1}\times \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ . I can see that why this is intuitively true. That is we have $\Bbb{C}^{*}=S^{1}\times \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ and the action of $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$ makes the quotient $\Bbb{C}^{*}/\Bbb{Z_{2}}\cong \frac{S^{1}}{\Bbb{Z}_{2}}\times \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ .
But I cannot figure out how explicitly is $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$ acting on the set.

EDIT:- I think I have it. The quotient space of $S^{1}$ under the action is just $S^{1}$ with $0\leq \theta\leq\pi$ with $\theta\sim \pi -\theta$ and for $\pi\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ we have $\theta \sim 3\pi - \theta $ and for the circle we must have $0\sim 2\pi$ . This would be homeomorphic to $\partial([0,1]\times [0,1])$ with $(x,1)\sim (1,x)$ and $(x,0)\sim (0,x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Thus if we define $f:\partial(I^{2})\to I$ by $f(x,0)=\frac{x}{2}=f(0,x)$ and $f(x,1)=f(1,x)=\frac{1+x}{2}$ , then it descends to a homeomorphism from the quotient $\partial I^{2}/\sim $ to $[0,1]$ . Can you verify if all of these are correct?

Comment: Can you solve a simpler question: instead of $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, what is the quotient space $\mathbb C/\sim$ with $x+iy \sum \pm x + iy$ homeomorphic to?

Comment: @ArcticChar That is what I am precisely having the trouble figuring out. I know that I must get to $\Bbb{R}P^{1}\times (0,\infty)$ somehow but I cannot understand what the explicit action should be which makes these spaces homeomorphic. That is , for example I know $(r,\theta)\sim (r,\pi-\theta)$ in terms of polar. But how do I justify the action of $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$.

Comment: Why must you get to $\mathbb{RP}^1 \times (0, \infty)$? The action is that question is different from yours.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am having difficulty in what exactly the action is on $S^{1}$ and the why and the what the $\frac{S^{1}}{\Bbb{Z}_{2}}$ is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "question here" you mention is about the antipodal action $z\mapsto-z$, different from yours.

Your reduction to $\Bbb{C}^{*}/\Bbb{Z_{2}}\cong \frac{S^{1}}{\Bbb{Z}_{2}}\times \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ is correct, but your $\frac{S^{1}}{\Bbb{Z}_{2}}$ is not $\Bbb{R}P^1$. It is $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ (each of the two bounds of this segment is alone in its orbit, while each of the other $\theta$'s has $\pi-\theta$ in its orbit).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more as to how explicitly is $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$ acting on $S^{1}$ . That is what I am having the trouble in conceptualizing. For example . If I have $\theta<0$ then $\pi-\theta>\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I think I have it. The quotient space is just $S^{1}$ with $0\leq \theta\leq\pi$ with $\theta\sim \pi -\theta$ and for $\pi\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ we have $\theta \sim 3\pi - \theta $ and for the circle we must have $0\sim 2\pi$ . This would be homeomorphic to $\partial([0,1]\times [0,1])$ with $(x,1)\sim (1,x)$ and $(x,0)\sim (0,x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Thus if we define $f:\partial(I^{2})\to I$ by $f(x,0)=\frac{x}{2}=f(0,x)$ and $f(x,1)=f(1,x)=\frac{1+x}{2}$ , I get the homeomorphism to $[0,1]$ . Can you verify if all of these are correct?

Comment: It is correct but much too complicated. Just define $f:S^1\to\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ by $f^{-1}(\theta)=\{e^{i\theta},e^{i(\pi-\theta)}\}$.